# Strings turn to gibberish when opening excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, c#, hebrew

I'm working at a company that have a running web-app for accounting management.
I've recently received a complaint regarding exporting a report via email in excel format (the report contains characters in Hebrew):
For a specific user, when the report contains more than 10 rows (rather small in regards to the reports we usually produce), excel presents the strings in gibberish.

The weird thing is, this only happens for a specific user account, on multiple machines with multiple versions of excel, and is only relevant in excel, i.e. when I'm opening the file in Notepad, all the data is formatted correctly.

I've tried:
1. producing a similar report from a different user account with identical account settings.
2. sending the same report, split into 2 parts each with half the data.
3. removing a few rows via notepad and opening it in excel.
3.5 adding those rows again via notepad and opening the report again.
4. sending each data row as it's own report.
All of those things produced a **correct** file with the data rightly formatted.
I'd also like to note that the app is running for a few years now with 20K+ users, and so far this is the first time I've ran into this specific issue.

Does anyone have any idea what the cause may be?
Suggestions to what to check next?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at the language settings being used and compared that to an account where things work OK?

Comment: Yeah, I've even copied the account settings in their entirety to a different account, and it worked correctly.  I've also checked the issue on a different data set for the problematic user, and the same problem appeared - gibberish only when the report had more than 10 data rows.